# Is it possible dock "Search Everywhere" in Intellij to a sidebar?

Tags: intellij-idea

"Search Everywhere" feature within Intellij is a nice one, as it serves the similar purpose of a google search, but limited to our projects.

Is it possible to dock that floating toolbar to a sidebar, so that I could use it anytime?

Currently, the way, it is invoked is, by using "Shift Shift".

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not a floating toolbar, it is a popup. You can write a plugin for that. But why exactly you cannot use `shift shift` anytime?